# How to use vim variables the right way in these case?

Tags: vim, neovim

vimrc:

```
"set a variable
let g:location_pprefix='~/AppData/local'

"case1
if empty(glob(location_prefix.'/nvim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo location_prefix/nvim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
    \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source location_prefix/nvim/init.vim
endif

"case2
map ooo ilocation_prefix

"case3
set backupdir=location_pprefix/nvim/tmp/backup,.

"case4
noremap <silent> <LEADER>rc :e location_pprefix/nvim/init.vim<CR>
```

‍‍‎​﻿‎‏​﻿‌﻿​﻿‌‏​‏﻿‎​﻿‍﻿​﻿‏‎​﻿‎‎​﻿‍‏​﻿‎﻿​‏‏‌​‍﻿﻿​﻿‎﻿​‍﻿‌​﻿‌﻿​‍﻿‌​‍﻿﻿​﻿‍‏​﻿‎‏​﻿‌﻿ ‍‍‎​﻿‎‏​﻿‌﻿​﻿‌‏​‏﻿‎​﻿‍﻿​﻿‏‎​﻿‎‎​﻿‍‏​﻿‎﻿​‏‏‌​‍﻿﻿​﻿‎﻿​‍﻿‌​﻿‌﻿​‍﻿‌​‍﻿﻿​﻿‍‏​﻿‎‏​﻿‌﻿ ‍‍‎​﻿‎‏​﻿‌﻿​﻿‌‏​‏﻿‎​﻿‍﻿​﻿‏‎​﻿‎‎​﻿‍‏​﻿‎﻿​‏‏‌​‍﻿﻿​﻿‎﻿​‍﻿‌​﻿‌﻿​‍﻿‌​‍﻿﻿​﻿‍‏​﻿‎‏​﻿‌﻿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all of those situations, you could use `:execute` to concatenate the variable into the command.

```
exe "silent !curl -fLo ".g:location_prefix."/nvim/autoload/plug.vim..."
autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | exe "source ".g:location_prefix."/nvim/init.vim"
```

The `:map` examples can be done more simply using `<expr>` (see `:help :map-expression`).

```
map <expr> ooo "i".g:location_prefix
noremap <expr> <silent> <LEADER>rc ":e ".g:location_prefix."/nvim/init.vim<CR>"
```

As for the `:set` example, you can do it by using `:let` instead (options can be accessed as variables prefixed by `&`):

```
let &backupdir = location_prefix."/nvim/tmp/backup,."
```